# Is a nilpotent group of order 200 always such that all of its subgroups are normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I tried proving this false with $G=D_4 \times C_{25}$ and $G=Q_8 \times C_{25}$. In both cases, both of its Sylow $2,5-$subgroups are normal, and I don't see how else to show one of its subgroups is not normal. Is the result maybe true, and if yes, how do you prove it?

Comment: $D_8$  (or $D_4)$ has a subgroup that is not normal. Therefore this subgroup is not normal in $D_8\times C_{25}$.

Comment: @Levent So obvious, I'd completely forgotten. Thank you.